# SSRS Indicator affecting group by

Tags: reporting-services, indicator

I am filtering a tablix and then grouping both rows (total of 3) and columns (total of 2), with no detail section.  One row only has an applicable value for one of the grouped columns.  The group by places all of the values in the correct cell.  However, if I add an indicator, the row without an applicable value for the column inherits data from another row.  Adding the field that the indicator is based on does not make this change.  This row (and others that are working correctly) has a null value for the indicator in the first column, IE it shouldn't show up.

Dataset:

```
+---------+---------------+-----------+---------+
| Family  |  Description  |  Value    |Indicator|
+---------+---------------+-----------+---------+
|  A      |  Something    |   5       |    2    |
|  A      |  Another      |   2       |    1    |  
|  B      |  Yearly Plans |   63      |   null  | 
|  B      |  Weekly Plans |   4       |    2    | 
|  B      |  Yearly Qual  |   .4      |    1    | 
|  B      |  Weekly Qual  |   .2      |    1    | 
|  B      |  Purchased %  |   .76     |   null  | 
+---------+---------------+-----------+---------+
```

- Filter tablix for Family = B
- Row Group: =iif(Field!Description.Value like "*Plans*","Plans",iif(Field!Description.Value like "*Qual*","Qualifying",Field!Description.Value))
- Column Group:  iif(Field!Description.Value like "Yearly*","YTD","Weekly")

Result without indicators:

```
+---------------+------------+----------+
| Description   |  Weekly    |  YTD     |
+---------------+------------+----------+
|  Qualifying   |   .2       |   .4     | 
|  Plans        |    4       |   63     | 
|  Purchased %  |   .76      |          | 
+---------------+------------+----------+
```

Result with indicators (Based on indicator field):

```
+---------------+--------+---+--------+---+
| Description   | Weekly |   |  YTD   |   |
+---------------+--------+---+--------+---+
|  Qualifying   |   .2   | - |   .4   | - | 
|  Plans        |    4   | + |   63   |   | 
|  Purchased %  |   .76  |   |   .4   | - | 
+---------------+------------+--------+---+
```

What it SHOULD be:

```
+---------------+--------+---+--------+---+
| Description   | Weekly |   |  YTD   |   |
+---------------+--------+---+--------+---+
|  Qualifying   |   .2   | - |   .4   | - | 
|  Plans        |    4   | + |   63   |   | 
|  Purchased %  |   .76  |   |        |   | 
+---------------+------------+--------+---+
```

I have patched the current problem by unioning in a Yearly Purchased % row with null values, but there must be something else going one.  Is there something in how indicator's behave that would add values that aren't part of a group?

Answer (score 2):

I realized the same thing, could it be a bug in SSRS indicators, as workaround, you can write an expression inside the cell to check against another cell and investigate if there is data then show the value inside the cell, if not then write nothing.

like: `=iif(count(Fields!Field1.Value)>1,"",Fields!Field2.Value)`